# Finding values above threshold extremely slow

Tags: c++, vector

I've got code which needs to find at what points in time a laser has been fired. The laser is indicated by a DC of above 500 on the dataset, and comes in bulks of 3 lasers at a time, in rather quick, but not entirely deterministic, time gaps.

The code I am using right now:

```
//std::vector<short>& laserData; this one comes from the function call, this is the definition
int count = 0;

for(unsigned int index = 0; index < laserData.size(); ++index) {
    if(laserData.at(index) > 500) {
        times.push_back(index);
        count = (count + 1)%3;
        if(count == 0) {
            int dif1 = times.at(times.size()-1) - times.at(times.size()-2);
            int dif2 = times.at(times.size()-1) - times.at(times.size()-3);
            if(dif1 > 60000 || dif2 > 60000) {
                times.erase(times.begin() + times.size() - 2);
                times.erase(times.begin() + times.size() - 2);
                count = 1;
            }
        }

        switch(count) {
            case 0: index += 90000;
            default: index += 2000;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't be entirely sure that all 3 laser impulses always happen, and if they don't, the complete set of those 1 or 2 laser impulses needs to be removed.

The dataset is 130,000,000 samples long, and I get about 3300 laser impulses in total, so that works fine, its just darned slow. It takes about 45 seconds to parse that vector, and I wonder if there is a faster way to do that.

Comment: It appears you could do it in parallel, but why do you skip ahead in the list when you find a value greater than 500?

Comment: Using `.at()` is much slower than the `[]` operator, as `.at()` does bounds checking that `[]` does not.

Comment: Also, using `.erase()` is costly, I believe. Why do you have the `erase` function twice in your code? You should only be calling it once if at all.

Comment: I can skip ahead in the data when I found something, since I know the lasers 1 to 2 to 3 are at least 2000 samples apart, and 3 to 1 is at least 90000 away-

Comment: erase is called a maximum of 2 times in total.

Comment: That `switch` statement adds `92000` to index in case `count == 0` is that desired behavior (not the case for performance drop, but still).
Also, besides not using `at` I'd suggest dropping the modulo operator in count increment.

Comment: @SinisterMJ Calling it more than once is bad, if you're trying to squeeze performance out (while maintaining readability). Also, your switch statement is borked. See: http://ideone.com/NitBmN as an example for why your switch statement is bad. EDIT: And here is what the switch statement SHOULD look like: http://ideone.com/Dz1r0A

Comment: @SinisterMJ Are you compiling with compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: @SinisterMJ I think it would help if you random-generated a likely input in `laserData` in the question.

Comment: I can compile the code only in debug mode due to some old library used, but I use #pragma optimization ("", on) and ("", off) before and after that function.

Comment: Well, how many points are actually >500 in the array?

Comment: You should declare your `vector` with a large (huge) size, so that it doesn't resize.  Resizing of an array or vector is slow.  Erasing items in a vector is another hog of execution time.  A faster option is to copy the valid times to another vector.

Comment: @clcto because while the gap between pulses is not exact, it will be greater than 'a limit'. Increasing index by this lower bound reduces the search space and so improves execution time of the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Unless you intended the switch statement to fall-through, add in a break:

```
switch(count)
{
    case 0: 
        index += 90000;
        break;
    default: 
        index += 2000;
}
```

Ok. now we have a potential error out of the way, we can look at speeding up your code.

The first thing to do is to eliminate as much of the vector resizing as possible.
you said there were about 3300 laser pulses in total. Lets add ~10% margin of error to that and resize the vector of pulses in advance:

```
times.reserve(3600);
```

Now the vector should not need to be resized multiple times. If there are more, we should only have the vector realovating once.

Next, we want to get rid of the `times.erase()` function calls.
To do this, we cache the three most recent values separately, and only push them into the vector once they have been validified:

```
const int pulse_interval =  2000;
const int burst_interval = 90000;
int cache[3];
times.reserve(3600);
for(unsigned int index = 0; index < laserData.size(); ++index) 
{
    if(laserData[index] > 500) 
    {
        //this next if block acts as our guard clause
        if (count > 0)
        {
            diff = index - cache[count-1];
            if (diff > 60000)
            {
                count = 1;
                cache[0]=index;
                index+= pulse_interval;
                continue;
                // if gap between pulses is too big reset and start again, setting most recent value to first of next sequence.
            }
        }
        //now we actually store data in the cache and if needed add to the vector. No invalid data (not part of a three burst set) should reach here due to guard
        cache[count]=index;
        if (count == 2)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
                {times.push_back(cache[i]);}
            count = 0;
            index += burst_interval;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            index += pulse_interval;
        }
        //updating count at the end is easier to follow
        //goes to 0 after 3rd pulse detected
    }
}
```

This removes vector access with invalid data and should speed up the code as much as a quick answer here can do.

edit: added in your index skipping parameters. If I got the logic wrong, let me know. In this case, the switch isnt needed as the logic could be encapsulated in the existing logic from the algorithm.

If you can't turn optimisation on, then you can try unrolling the `push_back` loop. Cache array can be reduced to two cells, and storing of the `index` can be moved to the `else` (for the third value just `push_back(index);`
This removes the loop overhead and one assignment for each time you find a full burst. Your compiler would handle this normally.

If still slow. then you need to profile. Make sure that your `index` skips are of the right size (too small means you search too much, but too large and you risk loosing valid data)

You could also do this in parallel as a commenter suggested. You could do this splitting the search space into a number of sections and spawning a thread for each section.

Comment: As you've accepted my answer,  I'd be interested in how much it has helped. Your dataset is quite large so it will still take some time but it is hopefully noticeably faster.